# How to unlock the Cherry Blossom and Rave Queen outfits?

Tags: dojo-quest

I managed to beat the dragon twice during a run but Cherry Blossom and Rave Queen are still locked in the Wardrobe.  I noticed that as I beat levels the screen would notify me of unlocking a new outfit.  When those stopped happening, I assumed I unlocked all 7, but that is not the case.

How can I unlock the last 2 outfits in the Wardrobe, Cherry Blossom and Rave Queen?

Answer (score -1):

I go a high score of 1943680 and was able to unlock cherry blossom. Still no rave queen.